# How do I change the names of options in the paragraph format drop down menu in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

I would like to change the name of 'Header 3' to 'Header' in CKEditor (I have removed all other options besides 'Normal'). How would I do this?

Additionally, if anyone knows how to make the drop down box smaller, that would also be very helpful!

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I edited the files under lang in format!

Comment: The please mark your question as solved to not to distract users.